# Dotnet restore fails when providing runtime identifier due to transitive dependency

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

Why does my build/restore fail when providing a runtime-identifier `win-x64`? Why does it work when I don't? I stumbled across this when trying out self-contained builds.

To put it differently: Why do `dotnet restore --runtime win-x64` and `dotnet restore` have different dependency graphs?

It works when I use `netcoreapp2.1` as a target framework, but it breaks with `netcoreapp3.1` or `net5.0`. It also works when I remove either of my direct dependencies.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.23" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate" Version="2.0.9" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

```
> dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored ...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj (in 289 ms).

> dotnet restore --runtime win-x64

  Determining projects to restore...
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Console 4.0.0 -> runtime.win.System.Console 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Console 4.0.0 -> runtime.win.System.Console 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Text.Encoding.Extensions from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Console 4.0.0 -> runtime.win.System.Console 4.3.0 -> System.Text.Encoding.Extensions (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Text.Encoding.Extensions (>= 4.0.11) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Handles from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Text.Encoding.Extensions from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Text.Encoding.Extensions (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Text.Encoding.Extensions (>= 4.0.11) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Win32.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Tracing from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Handles from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Tracing from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Net.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.0.11) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Handles from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Tracing from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Buffers 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Tracing (>= 4.1.0) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Win32.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.3.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)  [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj : error NU1605:  ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives (>= 4.0.1) [...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.sln]
  Failed to restore ...\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj (in 406 ms).
```

I know I can "fix" it by adding these dependencies, but I would prefer a better solution.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Primitives" Version="4.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem" Version="4.3.0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

First, a nit on terminology. `netcoreapp2.1`, `netcoreapp3.1` and `net5.0` are generally called **Target Frameworks** (and more formally Target Framework Monikers, often abbreviated to TFM). **Runtime Identifers** (often abbreviated to RID) identify a platform that .NET (Core) is running on top of. They include `linux-x64` (Linux on x86_64), `win-arm64` (Windows on Arm64) and so on.

A Target Framework identifies the Framework that your application is targeting. A Target Framework includes a number of assemblies (such as `System.Collections.Generic`, or `System.Runtime.InteropServices`) that it contains. All those assemblies are at specific versions.

`Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate`, as an assembly, also depends on other assemblies. You can see such a few such dependency chains in your output:

```
ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.3.0)
ConsoleApp1 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFileAlternate 2.0.9 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Runtime.InteropServices (>= 4.1.0)
```

Looking at the second line first, it says Serilog depends on the NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 (equivalent to `netstandard1.6` TFM), which depends on a particular version of `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, 4.1.0.

The first line says that Serilog depends on `Microsoft.Win32.Primitives`, which depends on the runtime package `runtime.win.Microsoft.Win32.Primitives`. As I understand it, these `runtime.*` packages are provided by your .NET SDK/Runtime installation. So using this leads to a dependency on a newer version of `System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

Because two different dependency chains lead to two different versions of `System.Runtime.InteropServices being required, this gets flagged as a downgrade.

If you use `netcoreapp2.1` (.NET Core 2.1), that has the `runtime.win.Microsoft.Win32.Primitives` package at the lower (and matching) version (4.1.0). In that case, all dependency chains would lead to the same version, and there's no package downgrade identified.

Comment: So why do `dotnet restore --runtime win-x64` and `dotnet restore` have different dependency graphs?